# OpenUI5 Application Routing Issue: Views Not Loading for Subroutes under Component Usage

Tags: sapui5

I have an OpenUI5 application with the following folder structure:

[image: Folder structure of my UI5 project incl. the reuse component]

The two `manifest.json` files are defined as follows:

Main **`manifest.json`**:

```json
{
    "_version": "1.48.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sigesor",
        "type": "application",
        "...": "..."
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "...": "..."
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "...": "...",
        "componentUsages": {
            "fua": {
                "name": "sigesor.reuse.fua",
                "settings": {},
                "componentData": {},
                "lazy": true
            }
        },
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sigesor.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.65.6",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewPath": "sigesor.view",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "async": true,
                "propagateTitle": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "login",
                    "target": "login"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "fua",
                    "name": "fua",
                    "target": {
                        "name": "fua",
                        "prefix": "f"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "login": {
                    "viewName": "Login",
                    "viewId": "login",
                    "viewPath": "sigesor.view",
                    "controlId": "root"
                },
                "fua": {
                    "type": "Component",
                    "usage": "fua",
                    "title": "FUA",
                    "viewId": "fuaComponent",
                    "controlId": "root"
                }
            }
        },
        "resourceRoots": {
            "thirdparty": "thirdparty",
            "util": "util"
        }
    }
}
```

Reuse **`manifest.json`**:

```json
{
    "_version": "1.48.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "id": "sigesor.reuse.fua",
        "type": "application",
        "...": "..."
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "technology": "UI5",
        "...": "..."
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "...": "...",
        "rootView": {
            "viewName": "sigesor.reuse.fua.view.App",
            "type": "XML",
            "async": true
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.65.6",
            "libs": {
                "sap.ui.layout": {},
                "sap.ui.core": {},
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewPath": "sigesor.reuse.fua.view",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "Observado",
                    "target": "observado"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "extemporaneo",
                    "name": "Extemporaneo",
                    "target": "extemporaneo"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "reconsideraciones",
                    "name": "Reconsideraciones",
                    "target": "reconsideraciones"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "extemporaneo": {
                    "viewPath": "sigesor.reuse.fua.view.registro",
                    "viewName": "Extemporaneo",
                    "viewId": "Extemporaneo",
                    "controlId": "root"
                },
                "observado": {
                    "viewPath": "sigesor.reuse.fua.view.registro",
                    "viewName": "Observado",
                    "viewId": "Observado",
                    "controlId": "root"
                },
                "reconsideraciones": {
                    "viewPath": "sigesor.reuse.fua.view",
                    "viewName": "Reconsideraciones",
                    "viewId": "Reconsideraciones",
                    "controlId": "root"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to access by changing the URL to "/fua/extemporaneo", it doesn't load the corresponding view (Nothing happens). However, when I access "/fua" it successfully loads the view for the empty pattern (`"Observado"` target). What could be the error?

I tried to changing the routes patterns to "fua/extemporaneo" or "fua/reconsideraciones", but it did not work.